# Image container not aligning bottom to other grid container

Tags: html, css

[image]
Hello,

As you can see from the photo above, I am trying to achieve a grid system. First grid is 3 images, second grid is a column, and third grid is a large image floated to the right of the 2nd grid. You can see this photo on my portfolio website: http://www.irwinlitvak.com

I have three images in the first grid that have a width of 31.33% and the first and second img have a margin-right of 3.005% to full up the container width.

In the next grid (grid-2), I have a two of my images floated left in a column and (grid-2-of-3) is floated right with a width of 65.556%.

I would like the top and bottom of the larger image to take up the full height of the grid, so the bottom of the big image aligns with the self-destructing box.

Here is the HTML & CSS:

```css
.projects-grid {
  margin: 100px auto 0;
  width: 90%;
}

.projects-grid .title {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.projects-grid h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Montserrat";
}

.grid-1 {
  margin-bottom: 4%;
}

.grid-1-of-3 {
  position: relative;
  width: 31.33%;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.grid-2-of-3 {
  position: relative;
  width: 65.556%;
  float: right;
}

.grid-1-of-3:first-child,
.grid-1-of-3:nth-child(2) {
  margin-right: 3.005%;
}

.grid-3 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33%;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.grid-5 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.box-1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.grid-1-of-3:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.grid-1-of-3:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.big-box {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.grid-2 {
  width: 31.33%;
  float: left;
}

.grid-2 .box-cont {
  width: 100%;
}

.grid-2 .box-cont:first-child {
  margin-bottom: 4%;
}

.grid-2 .box-cont {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<section class="projects-grid clearfix">

  <div class="row title">
    <h2>Projects</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="grid-1 clearfix">
    <div class="grid-1-of-3">

      <div class="box-1">
        <a href="">
          <img class="bdgt-app" src="assets/budget-app-x-ps.jpg" alt="budget-app pic">
        </a>
        <a href="https://budget-app-x.herokuapp.com/" target="_blank">
          <div class="box-overlay">
            <div class="text-overlay">
              <h3>Budget-App-X</h3>
              <p>Manage your incomes and expenses in a fun and easy app.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>

      <h3>
        <a href="https://budget-app-x.herokuapp.com/" target="_blank">Budget-App-X</a>
      </h3>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-1-of-3">
      <div class="box-1">
        <a href="">
          <img src="/assets/dice-game-x-ps.jpg" alt="dice-game">
        </a>
        <a href="https://dice-game-x.herokuapp.com/" target="_blank">
          <div class="box-overlay">
            <div class="text-overlay">
              <h3>Dice-Game</h3>
              <p>Roll the dice. Test your luck and see who racks the most points.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <h3>
        <a href="https://dice-game-x.herokuapp.com/" target="_blank">Dice-Game</a>
      </h3>

    </div>

    <div class="grid-1-of-3">
      <div class="box-1">
        <a href="">
          <img src="/assets/pomodoro-timer-x-ps.jpg" alt="pomodoro-app-timer">
        </a>
        <a href="http://pomodoro-app-timer.herokuapp.com" target="_blank">
          <div class="box-overlay">
            <div class="text-overlay">
              <h3>Pomodoro-Timer</h3>
              <p>A quick and easy solution to being productive. Set the time and get things done.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>

      <h3>
        <a href="http://pomodoro-app-timer.herokuapp.com" target="_blank">Pomodoro-Timer</a>
      </h3>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="grid-2 clearfix">

    <div class="box-cont">
      <div class="box-1">
        <a href="">
          <img src="/assets/cucumberme-x-ps.jpg" alt="cucumber me">
        </a>
        <a href="http://www.cucumberme.com" target="_blank">
          <div class="box-overlay">
            <div class="text-overlay">
              <h3>CucumberMe</h3>
              <p>CucumberMe is your way of anonymously sending cucumbers to a friend, ex or anyone you want.<br><br> Go and send one today! </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>

      <h3>
        <a href="http://www.cucumberme.com" target="_blank">CucumberMe</a>
      </h3>

    </div>

    <div class="box-cont">
      <div class="box-1">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="/assets/self-destruct-x-ps.jpg" alt="to do list">
        </a>
        <a href="http://todos-irwin.herokuapp.com/" target="_blank">
          <div class="box-overlay">
            <div class="text-overlay">
              <h3>Self Destructing To-Do-List</h3>
              <p>A to-do-list that will delete itself within 10 seconds. How many chores can you list within that time? </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <h3>
        <a href="http://todos-irwin.herokuapp.com/" target="_blank"> 
                                Self Destructing To-Do-List
                            </a>
      </h3>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="grid-2-of-3 clearfix">
    <div class="box-cont">
      <div class="big-box">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="/assets/omnifood-x-ps.jpg" alt="omnifood">
        </a>
        <a href="http://con.staging.thegateny.net/con/Omnifood/v1/" target="_blank">
          <div class="box-overlay big-overlay">
            <div class="text-overlay">
              <h3>Omnifood</h3>
              <p>My version of the food app Blue Apron. Take a look! </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>

      <h3>
        <a href="http://con.staging.thegateny.net/con/Omnifood/v1/" target="_blank">
                                Omnifood
                            </a>
      </h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: If you want it to 'fill up' the height, it's going to stretch the image no?

Comment: That would stretch the image, I am trying to achieve what this guy did in his website - http://wootten.ca/ .

If you scroll briefly, you will see he has one large image the same height as the two smaller floated images

Comment: well fixing the widths/heights definitely won't be helpful unless you know their exact dimensions. I'd probably have a try at flexboxes

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is as I show in the snippet below. You have a container for all your divs you want at the same height, which you give a set height. You then give the items on the left a container (with `height: 100%`) and make a div for the right item (`height: 100%`).
By doing this, you have a container for the items on the left, so you can make them, say, 50% each, and you have a right item that's the same height as the container on the left.

In order to make an image fit a div, either use `background-size: cover` or something similar. `height:100%; width: auto` also works for responsive images.

Hope it helps.

```css
.outer {
background: blue;
width: 600px;
height: 200px;
}

.leftwrap {
width: 30%;
float: left;
height: 100%;
}

.left1 {
background: purple;
width: 100%;
height: 50%;
}

.left2 {
background: orange;
width: 100%;
height: 50%;
}

.right {
background: teal;
height: 100%;
width: 70%;
float: left;
}

/** New code **/
.image {
  height: 80%;
  width: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.imagetext {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.left {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class='outer'>
  <div class='leftwrap'>
    <div class='left left1'>
      <div class="image">My image here</div>
      <div class="imagetext">Some text</div>
    </div>
    <div class='left left2'>
      <div class="image">My image here</div>
      <div class="imagetext">Some text</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='right'>3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey Friso,

In the design i posted I wanted a margin bottom on the first small box so the text (title of project) underneath can have space. If you look at my website (http://www.irwinlitvak.com) you would understand. Plus i'm trying to mimic the design of  http://wootten.ca .

Comment: I updated the answer. Basically, you want to treat the left1 and left2 elements as containers for an image and text. With `box-sizing: border-box`, you can then add padding without upsizing the div. The padding now is 30px to illustrate the example rather than look nice.